# onbeforeunload in safari does not run code server side

Tags: javascript, safari, onbeforeunload

On browser close or F5, I have to perform some code on server side
For this I have a button.  On click of that button which has onclientclick and onclick functions written.  I also wrote an event on window.onbeforeunload which does a button.click().

```
window.onbeforeunload=function(e)
{
   button.click()
}
```

My problem is that this runs the code of the client side click function of the button, however server side code does not get executed.  This happens only when i close the browser.  When I do F5 it works perfectly.  Also this happens only on Safari.  In FF and mozila it works perfectly .  How can i

Comment: How do you invoke your "server-side code"?  What does your "click" handler look like?

Answer (score 1):

Safari does not allow or execute asynchronous AJAX requests in beforeunload events, so it might very well be that your code is executed but that the requests are never issued to the server. Synchronous AJAX requests are executed, so use those in the beforeunload handler.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a speed issue, the button gets clicked but the response isn't being sent to the server fast enough, so the browser closes before it can be sent.

If you need to, you can always throw up a prompt to slow the closing of the window down, but this is very unfriendly.

Comment: That's not true--mobile safari doesn't recognize onbeforeunload, but desktop safari does.

Answer (score 0):

as a curiosity, The problem here is taht Safari does not recognize the onbeforeunload event... therefore any code there will not be run in Safari. 
You could use onunload event but here you will never be able to prevent the page from closing